# Python csv.reader vs csv.dictreader differences?

Tags: python

Have two scripts that give very different results. First using csv.reader and it works fine, then csv.dictreader which has given me problems. Both scripts use the same set of data, only difference between the two files is that the one dictreader uses has headers.

```
import csv

inv = csv.reader(open('inv.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel', delimiter="\t")

for PART_CODE,MODEL_NUMBER,PRODUCT_NAME,COLOR,TOTAL_ONHAND,TOTAL_ON_ORDER,TOTAL_SALES,SALES_YEAR_TO_DATE,SALES_LASTYEAR_TO_DATE,\
TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_QTYsSOLD,TOTAL_PURCHASES,PURCHASES_YEAR_TO_DATE,PURCHASES_LASTYEAR_TO_DATE,TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_QTYpurchased,DATE_LAST_SOLD,DATE_FIRST_SOLD in inv:
    if int(TOTAL_ON_ORDER) >= 1:
        print ('%-20s %-100s OnHand: %-4s OnOrder: %-4s') % (MODEL_NUMBER,PRODUCT_NAME,TOTAL_ONHAND,TOTAL_ON_ORDER)
```

The above works just fine, it'll parse through the 20,000 plus items with no error. Now if I choose to use dictreader as in the below, the script will run into problems after a while...

```
import csv

inv = csv.DictReader(open('ireport.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel', delimiter="\t")

for row in inv:
    if int(row['TOTAL_ON_ORDER']) >= 1:
        print ('%-20s %-100s OnHand: %-4s OnOrder: %-4s') % (row['MODEL_NUMBER'],row['PRODUCT_NAME'],row['TOTAL_ONHAND'],row['TOTAL_ON_ORDER'])
```

Prints out about 100 or so, then fails and reports this error:

```
if int(row['TOTAL_ON_ORDER']) >= 1:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'False'
```

Puzzles me as both scripts use the same data (other than the reader one has no header row and the dictreader one does) one works flawlessly, the other complains. Any clues?

Snippet of inv.txt:

```
61965901576 383964  Sandisk 128MB 3.3V Smartmedia Card      0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   00/00/00    00/00/00
61965901521 348236  Sandisk 128MB Compactflash Card     0   0   54.26   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   01/09/02    01/09/02
61965902011 SDCZ2-1024-A10  Sandisk 1GB Cruzer Mini USB Flash Drive     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   00/00/00    00/00/00
61965901571 266796  Sandisk 256MB CompactFlash Disk     0   0   678.22  0   0   5   0   0   0   0   06/27/02    03/08/02
```

Comment: What happens if you change (in your `DictReader` code) `dialect='excel-tab'` to `dialect='excel'`?

Comment: What happens if you change `ireport.txt` to `inv.txt`?

Comment: Then it would break as ireport.txt is inv.txt, but has a header row.

Comment: Are there `False` values in the csv? Could `TOTAL_ON_ORDER` somehow be associated with the wrong column?

Comment: Nothing but intergers in the csv column for TOTAL_ON_ORDER, it is associating the right columns in the output before it croaks.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of `ireport.txt`? Especially after 100 lines or so (where it breaks).

Comment: Files used with the csv module should be opened in binary mode.  `'rb'` in Python 2, `newline=''` in Python 3.  Does that help?

Comment: When I do open it in binary mode, I get: _csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: No, but it indicates either badly formed input, or your dialect isn't quite right.  Can you post an actual sample via pastebin that can reproduce the error with your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's reading something as a Boolean into an integer (which it's not happy with) in the `DictReader` function, whereas in the `reader` function it is not getting that cast as such.

Try this:

```
import csv

inv = csv.DictReader(open('ireport.txt', 'rU'), dialect='excel', delimiter="\t")

for row in inv:
    try:
      if int(row['TOTAL_ON_ORDER']) >= 1:
          print ('%-20s %-100s OnHand: %-4s OnOrder: %-4s') % (row['MODEL_NUMBER'],row['PRODUCT_NAME'],row['TOTAL_ONHAND'],row['TOTAL_ON_ORDER'])
    except Exception as Err:
      print row['TOTAL_ON_ORDER'],Err
      break #if you want to end the function)
```

This will show you what line it's choking on, and if you remove the break should chug through it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, the error report I was getting from python wasn't accurate enough, apparently there was something in there causing it to set to None, so I added an or row['DATE_LAST_SOLD'] == None and set it to 0 and all was well.